# Deduplicating rows using GROUP BY. Issue with Max()

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

```
SELECT BVDID, max(case when CompanynameLatinalphabet='' then NULL else CompanynameLatinalphabet end) as CompanynameLatinalphabet, idField1, idField2 FROM `imported_companies_BVD` where BVDID=103327
group by BVDID, CompanynameLatinalphabet
```

Hi everyone. In the below statement, I am getting:

```
BVDID  | CompanynameLatinalphabet          | idField1 | idField2
103327 | NULL                              | 100      |       1
103327 | CASEIFICIO SOCIALE DI RAV...      | NULL     |       1
```

How can I prevent the row with NULL be retrieved? I can not use IS NOT NULL in the where statement, as there are other columns that have data in the row.

The whole idea is merging the whole thing, there are values in BOTH ROWS that should be merged into as single row.
Thanks if you can help!

The expected result should be:

```
BVDID  | CompanynameLatinalphabet         | idfield1 | idfield2
103327 | CASEIFICIO SOCIALE DI RAV...     |      100 |        1
```

Comment: *I can not use IS NOT NULL in the where statement, as there are other columns that have data in the row.* What's the actual, complete criteria for skipping the row? Do you mean you want to skip rows that have `CompanynameLatinalphabet` NULL and NULL for everything else?

Comment: So what is your expected output here?

Comment: The issue is that there rows that have mixed values. I mean, the same two rows can have an ID being null and and ID not being null. So you'd say "ignore the one with id being null in the where clause. But the row can have useful columns and shouldn't be ignored, so the whole idea is merging everything not being null into a single row.

Comment: Your expected results contain 2 columns: idField1 and idField2 which are not mentioned in the query.

Comment: Is there a case for a BVID to exist more than 1 non null and non empty CompanynameLatinalphabets?

Comment: I think I understand what's going on. The max is working fine, the problem is that sometimes idfield2 doesn't have the same value, so in those cases it's obvious that it has to return more than ONE row

Comment: Then edit your question and clarify what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why use case statements in max function? If value is blank just return blank instead of null

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude the rows with `NULL` in the column `CompanynameLatinalphabet` you can do:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT
    BVDID, 
    max(case when CompanynameLatinalphabet='' then NULL 
             else CompanynameLatinalphabet end) as CompanynameLatinalphabet 
  FROM `imported_companies_BVD` 
  where BVDID=103327
  group by BVDID, CompanynameLatinalphabet
) x
where CompanynameLatinalphabet is not null
```

Comment: thanks The Impaler. Looks like it works. I am not understanding why the enclosing SELECT gets the desired result, when in fact it's just querying the SUB-SELECT.

Comment: @DiegoSendra Because it deals the the aggregated [resulting] value for the column, not the unaggregated values. That way it the filter becomes trivial.

Comment: the issue I see, is that if the row you are excluding with the where contains other columns that I want to be retrieved, then the whole row will be excluded.

Comment: is there a way to MIX two rows in mysql, ignoring just the null values without ignoring the whole row? I think WHERE is not the way to go

Comment: Please add the expected result to the question. It's not clear to me anymore.